# How to get value of AnimatedInterpolation

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

My question is how to retrieve the value of an AnimatedInterpolation in react-native, without calling private code.

I create the animated value and wrap it in an interpolation like this:

```
  animated = new Animated.Value();
  interpolated = this.animated.interpolate({
    inputRange:[0, 1000],
    outputRange:[0, 500]
  })
```

I render the animation like this:

```
  <Animated.View style={[{width: this.interpolated}]}/>
```

And I retrieve the animated value like this:

```
  this.animated.stopAnimation(v => {
    console.log(v, " ", this.interpolated.__getValue());
  })
```

Runnable example [here](https://snack.expo.io/HJjwpMniB).

My problem is that `__getValue()` is a private member of AnimatedInterpolation and it gives an error when using typescript. I'm looking for a sound way to retrieve the value, similarly to how `this.animated.stopAnimation` is sounder than `this.animated.__getValue()`.

Comment: I have no idea why there is no public `__getValue()` equivalent for `Animated.Value` or `Animated.AnimatedInterpolation`, or why there is no `AnimatedInterpolation.addEventListener` method, similar to `Animated.Value.addEventListener`. For some effects, such as external interpolators, I haven't figured a way around using `__getValue`, and it's disquieting.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to `interpolated` to get the value -

```js
    interpolated.addListener(({value}) => {
      console.log('interpolated', value)
    });
```

You can then use it with variables or anything.